# Creating a 2d array using types in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

Can you help me with this matrix declaration using types in VHDL?

```vhdl
-- A    B     Q    Y
(('0', '0', "000", 0),
 ('0', '1', "ZZ1", 1),
 ('1', '0', "Z1Z", 1),
 ('1', '1', "1ZZ", 2))
```

Comment: The aggregate shown expression represents a single dimensional array type with 4 elements. The element aggregate expressions represent a record type with 4 elements A, B, Q and Y. The types of the record elements aren't apparent from the aggregates. A and B could be std_logic for instance, Q a std_logic_vector and Y an integer type.

Comment: Record types are described in IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.3 Record types,  array types are described in 5.3.2 Array types. Also see 8. Names, 8.4 Indexed names and 8.3 Selected names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type declaration may look like this:

```
type element_t is record
  A : std_logic;
  B : std_logic;
  Q : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
  Y : natural;
end record;

type array_t is array (0 to 3) of element_t;

constant VALUE : array_t :=
  -- A    B     Q    Y
  (('0', '0', "000", 0),
   ('0', '1', "ZZ1", 1),
   ('1', '0', "Z1Z", 1),
   ('1', '1', "1ZZ", 2));
```

Let me suggest you get a VHDL compiler and simulator, like the free [ModelSim-Intel FPGA Starter Edition](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/software/programmable/quartus-prime/model-sim.html); then you can easily try come VHDL yourself.

Comment: There is no such thing as a column concatenation.

Comment: Not a *2d array* - "An array object is a composite object consisting of elements that have the same subtype." (IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2.1), This does not follow the mathematical definition "a rectangular array of quantities or expressions in rows and columns that is treated as a single entity and manipulated according to particular rules" It's not rectangular. An array is indexed, a record element is selected - [there's only one index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2vv9.jpg).

Comment: @user1155120: Your right, and it's an important comment.  Programmers entering VHDL from type relaxed languages, like Python, must get used to the strong type requirements of VHDL.  The construction is a single dimensional array (1D) array where the elements are records (not another array, even through the assignment looks it like that).